# Suspend, Resume Drop Down box is disabled in Debug Location Toolbar in VS 2012 Professional

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

[image: Disabled Debug Location Toolbar in VS 2012 Professional]

How to enable the Suspend, Resume drop down box in Debug Location Toolbar when I am debugging my VC++ window app.

Answer (score 2):

'Process Lifetime Management' and the 'application lifecycle' events combobox which come with it in VS are only for Windows Store apps. So you cannot enable it for a standard c++ gui application.